# Network Encryption with OpenSSL / AES explained

Tags: c++, security, encryption, cryptography

I`m really new to this, so I followed some tutorials, and made an example encrypt/decrypt in C++ for packets between client - server using a public and private key.

The results are quite promising, and working quite well, but I am confused, really confused, and I cannot make mistakes ( especially in a commercial environment ).

Please explain to me how I should use the encrypt/decrypt, at the moment I have:

- traffic encrypted with public key and decrypted with private key
- traffic encrypted with private key and decrypted with public key

I need to understand and know which is the correct method usage, this is what I understood ( please don't laugh ):

**

- SERVER (encrypts traffic with private key) -> CLIENT (decrypts
  traffic with public key)
- CLIENT (encrypts traffic with public key) -> SERVER (decrypts
  traffic with private key)

**

So my questions are as following:

- Is this correct what I have ?
- Does the public key go to the client,and the private key stays on the server ?
- Is there are other security issues that can occur?

Many thanks

Comment: Client , server are rather generic terms. Its is more like --- someone ( regardless of whether they are client or server ir whatever) generates a key pair - ( private and public key) and distributes the pulic key ( typically as a certificate ) and keeps private key.   Sure it is more common to have server side certificates that client side ... but sure some clients do have client certificates ...

Comment: Ok, and why did you downvote my question ? What`s the reason ?

Comment: Thank you everyone who downgraded my question without any reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cryptography is complicated and you should understand the protocols completely before you use them, especially in a commercial environment. So Ofer Arial is right, further reading is necessary.

But good thing you asked because your example is actually wrong. Here the corrected version:

- A encrypts traffic with B's public key -> B decrypts traffic with B's private key
- B encrypts traffic with A's public key -> A decrypts traffic with A's private key

I used A and B instead of server and client because the same applies to any kind of connection: server-client, client-client, server-server.

The overview shows that both the server and the client have their own key-pairs. In general, the sender always uses the receiver's public key to encrypt and the receiver uses his own private key to decrypt.

What's wrong with your version? Well, everyone with the public key could read the traffic sent to the client, so the encryption would make no sense.

Additionally to the encryption, the connection also requires an authentification, so each party knows that the (encrypted) message actually came from the correct person. So the key-pair 
is also used for authentification:

- A signs traffic with A's private key -> B's verifies that the traffic came from A with A's public key
- B signs traffic with B's private key -> A's verifies that the traffic came from B with B's public key

Doing both encryption and **authentification** are done with the same key-pair:

- The *private* key is used for *decryption* and *signing*.
- The *public* key is used for *encryption* and *verification*.

Now, how do A and B get the public keys and how can they ensure, that they got the correct ones? Either you meet and hand it too each other personally, or you use **certificates** of trusty parties.

This is just a short answer, but as already said further reading is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You want to learn about Asymetric Encryption (public-key encryption). 
Basically speaking, each side generates a pair of keys - (private key and public key, that are related somehow).

Learning about OpenSSL is related to ssl-certificates, and you have to understand that to work with ssl. Try reading: [SSL explained for beginners.](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/what-is-ssl#sm.000043e56tjn8dn5x1y1qlmpuwlkh)

It's not necassarily related to server-client.

**For example**, you have your pair of keys.

Then, your public key is sent to the your friend, and the friend encrypts the data with the public key you gave him and sends it to you.

Now, you can unlock (decrypt) the encryped data using your private key.

You can learn this important topic in the following resources:

1. From wiki: [Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)
2. Explaining videos: [Encryption types explained](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERp8420ucGs)
3. Asymetric encryption explained: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5FEqGYLL0o)
4. Public key encryption video: [With Diffie-Hellman example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEBfamv-_do)
5. For depper understanding: [RSA algorithem explanation+example](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_alg.html#simpleexample)

Comment: Thank you, I have a working example already and tested packet encryption, what is confusing me is the way I will use it...

Comment: So that's why I think you should read the links. If you want specific help, be specific about your problem. Read my explanation about the public-private key between you and your friend.